# How to exit ExecutorService after all the threads have done their execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, executor

This is the code which is working but I am specifying the wait time explicitly. Is there any way to exit `ExecutorService` when all the threads have completed their execution.

```
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    {
      for(final List<String> list:partitions){

       es.execute(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() {
      try{
            System.out.println(list);
            new CallAPI().make_call(list, access_token);    

        }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        }       
      }
     });
    Thread.sleep(5000);
   }
   boolean finshed = es.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
   es.shutdown();
```

`boolean finshed = es.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);`==>I am giving here wait time but I don't want this because I don't know when the thread will finish execution

Comment: The order of shutdown and awaitTermination are the wrong way around

Answer (score 2):

- use `Future<?> f = executor.submit(new Runnable(...));`
- store the futures in a list
- after the loop, iterate over the futures and call `f.get()`

This will block until all the tasks have been executed.

You can then call `executor.shutdown()`.

Comment: thanks for reply, I will check this.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want [ExecutorService.invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-). All you have to do is convert your collection of lists to a collection of Callables.

```
List<Callable<String>> tasks = partitions.stream()
    .map(list->{
         System.out.println(list);
         new CallAPI().make_call(list, access_token);
         return "finished";   
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Future<String>> futures = es.invokeAll(tasks);
es.shutdown();
```

Then you have the futures, you can use them to check for exceptions, or if the task completed ok.

Comment: thanks this has solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The following method shuts down an ExecutorService in two phases, first by calling shutdown to reject incoming tasks, and then calling shutdownNow, if necessary, to cancel any lingering tasks:

```
 void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

Comment: What is a task needs 3 minutes to complete?

Comment: thanks for reply, but I want all threads to execute properly and then shutdown executor.

Answer (score 0):

To terminate the ExecutorService when all tasks are finished, just call `es.shutdown()`. Your own thread will continue the execution, while the task-threads will process all queued tasks.

From Java Doc:

> shutdown
>   Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.
>   This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.

You need `awaitTermination`, when you want to block your own thread.